# ERROR 010658: Failure in distributed raster analytics operation. Error when using hydrology tool 'Fill'

Tags: arcgis-pro, hydrology, watershed, rivers

I'm currently doing a watershed delineation and river morphology computation using ArcGIS Pro. I have the DEM of the area and started with the hydrology tool "Fill" but it keeps having an error

> ERROR 010658:Failure in distributed raster analytics operation.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Try restarting ArcPro? Try putting a zero into the parallel processing factor in the tools environment settings, to turn off distribution?